# How to ensure consistent shuffling of X_train and y_train in Keras Data Generator in the on_epoch_end() function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a keras data generator class. One of the attributes is the `shuffle` which if set true when the class is initialised and the `on_epoch_end()` is called, it will shuffle the indices of the samples in the design matrix, which in our case is a np array where each sample contains the file path of the png image. Problem is I used the scikit-learn `X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(file_paths, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)` so if I only shuffle the indices of the `X_train` without appropriately shuffling the `y_train` in the same way, the X data will not match their correct labels if shuffle in the `on_epoch_end()`. Does anyone know how this can be approached? I will insert the code of my class for reference.

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, file_paths, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(240,320), n_channels=3, shuffle=True):
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.file_paths = file_paths
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
      'Updates indexes after each epoch'
      self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.file_paths))
      if self.shuffle == True:
          np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Given two lists (e.g. input and target paths), this shuffles them together:

```
tmp_list = list(zip(input_list, target_list))
np.random.shuffle(tmp_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the indices of X_train and y_train simultaneously using the same shuffled indices. Here's how you can modify your on_epoch_end() method to achieve this:
def on_epoch_end(self):
'Updates indexes after each epoch'
if self.shuffle:
# Generate shuffled indices
shuffled_indices = np.arange(len(self.file_paths))
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indices)

```
        # Shuffle both file_paths and labels arrays using the same shuffled indices
        self.file_paths = [self.file_paths[i] for i in shuffled_indices]
        self.labels = [self.labels[i] for i in shuffled_indices]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `on_epoch_end` method to achieve this:

```
def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes and shuffles data after each epoch'
    if self.shuffle:
        # Generate random indices
        idx = np.random.permutation(len(self.file_paths))
        # Shuffle file paths and labels
        self.file_paths = [self.file_paths[i] for i in idx]
        self.labels = [self.labels[i] for i in idx]
```